# Control Id Must match Identificator format in Kentico

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am getting the following error while adding Login form In kentico.: "**Control Id must match Identificator format**". Please help me to know why there is such an error and how can I be able to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the application and also restart the application. Just by doing this it works fine for me. Thanks :)